# StackedAreaChart - autorange bug

Tags: charts, javafx

My AreaChart with a category axis is behaving strange. First of all, the data goes way beyond the Y axis range. Secondly, the areacharts X axis doesn't start at the far left(first tick) , but on the second tick?

[image]

This is a MVCE:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    StackedAreaChart st;
    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data> xyList1
                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data<>("austria", 30),
                        new XYChart.Data<>("rr", 40),
                        new XYChart.Data<>("zz", 40),
                        new XYChart.Data<>("zq", 50),
                        new XYChart.Data<>("zr", 33),
                        new XYChart.Data<>("zw", 44));

        st.setAnimated(false);
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series(xyList1);
        st.getData().addAll(series1);

    }

}
```

If I remove this line:

```
new XYChart.Data<>("zq", 50)
```

the range is ok, but the tick still look strange.

Comment: I think we have again the same bug as we've already found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362719/barchart-linechart-only-the-label-for-the-last-data-point-showing). Only the last value is taking into account to calculate the chart Y range. With 44, the Y axis goes to 45. So any previous bigger values (50) are not shown, like in your picture.

Comment: So, I should file another bug to Oracle then?

Comment: Have you tested these issues under 8u40? I'm seeing on JIRA several fixes for charts already scheduled for 8u40.

Comment: Just tested 840 b10 with no luck. Animated `LineChart` still misses the labels except the last one, and `StackedAreaChart` values are still out of range if some of them are bigger than the last one. Time for more bug filing.

Comment: Thank you José ! Could you file it?

Comment: You've already done the other one, right? It's nearly the same bug, go ahead, please.

Comment: Do you want to add your answer? I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have again the same bug as we've already found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362719/barchart-linechart-only-the-label-for-the-last-data-point-showing). Only the last value is taking into account to calculate the chart Y range. So any previous bigger values are not properly shown.

A workaround for this is set auto range to false, and manually take care of it:

```
@FXML StackedAreaChart<String, Integer> st;
@FXML NumberAxis yAxis;

@FXML
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e){
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String,Integer>> xyList1
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new XYChart.Data<>("austria", 30),
                    new XYChart.Data<>("rr", 40),
                    new XYChart.Data<>("zz", 40),
                    new XYChart.Data<>("zq", 50),
                    new XYChart.Data<>("zr", 33),
                    new XYChart.Data<>("zw", 44));

    st.setAnimated(false);
    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series(xyList1);
    st.getData().addAll(series1);

    yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    yAxis.setLowerBound(Math.min(0,
        xyList1.stream().mapToInt(d->d.getYValue()).min().getAsInt()));
    yAxis.setUpperBound(xyList1.stream().mapToInt(d->d.getYValue()).max().getAsInt());
    yAxis.setTickUnit((yAxis.getUpperBound()-yAxis.getLowerBound())/10);

}
```

where in your FXML file you provide an `fx:id` for the Y axis:

```
<StackedAreaChart fx:id="st">
    <xAxis>
      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
      <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" side="LEFT" />
    </yAxis>
  </StackedAreaChart>
```